# Codekit 2 not refreshing browser

Tags: codekit

Codekit 2 does seem to be refreshing in any browsers. I've literally just installed it and been setting it up to my own preferences.

I use my Mac's hosts file to point http://localhost.sites to localhost. I've never had an issue with this in the past (I just set Codekit to refresh on any URL including the word localhost).

Now in the new settings file I'm slightly lost as to where to put it... after a load of mucking about I think I'm in a real state and here are my current settings:

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on this? Codekit is not refreshing the browser (all files are compiling fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan from Incident 57 told me, the refreshing process in Codekit 2 is totally different to the refreshing process in Codekit 1.

Codekit comes with its own server which you are required to run. You can click it in the top right hand corner of the program and it will launch.

You need to have this running to get going. If you have PHP files (or other server side code) Codekit won't run it – so this is where you need your external server running **but it is important that you still view the site you're testing at the address given** i.e. http://djave.local:5757.

For a far better explanation of all of this you can watch Bryan the creator of Codekit walk you through this in this video here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUgH0jlYur0

Comment: It's definitely possible to get live-reload to work without using the CodeKit server. That's just one way to do things. I have a local MAMP server that is live-reloaded just fine using that External Server Address URL.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, @Djave.

Now, while I won't assume you make the same mistakes I do, I found that some errors in my

were causing Chrome to ignore the refresh. Specifically, the closing  tag was missing. Instead, I had

```
<script... />
```

instead of

```
</script>
```

Hope you found the issue on your end.

Comment: If you have an error in eks a php script, codecit won't refresh the browser. You have to manually refresh the browser. I have this issue with Coda+MAMP.